# Visualizing directed preorders

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory

I am trying to understand directed preorders, a.k.a. directed sets. Are they analogous to connected DAGs?

Comment: One may visualize any preorder as follow. A preorder is a certain type of category. If the category is small, we may take it's nerve. One might also might be able to visualize this as a graph of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. A DAG cannot have edges $x\to y$ and $y\to x$, while a directed preorder can have $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$.

In general, you can visualize a preorder as the reachability relation on the vertices of a directed graph. Then a *directed* preorder corresponds to a graph where any two vertices are reachable from some third vertex.

Comment: So it is necessary that the directed graph be at least weakly connected.